# Why this usage doesn't seem right - "create speculation"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Here is the context.

> People speculate and do trading in stock marketing. There have been cases of people pumping money on a specific stock and creating a fake demand for it which in turn shoots up its price. `This will create speculation.`

Now, what is meant by last sentence is when people see a price of a stock going up, they tend to speculate without real knowledge as to why is it happening and  might buy the stock.

Is that the correct usage or is there a better phrase to convey the same thing?

For some reason, which I am unable to articulate, I find that phrase not accurate.  I feel its a usage like `create thought` where the appropriate usage would have been `triggered a thought`.

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127650/discussion-on-question-by-codeformer-why-this-usage-doesnt-seem-right-create).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/speculation), this is the Financial English definition of "speculation"

**the act of buying something hoping that its value will increase and then selling at this higher price in order to make a profit:**

- **speculation on/in sth** *Evidence that the economy is accelerating could fuel further speculation in commodity markets.*
- T*he share issue coincided with a huge rise in amateur stock market speculation.*

So yes, the word "speculation" can be used in this sense.

However, the original text does lack the expected fluidity for a small piece on financial market, since it is a bunch of short sentences. Here is a suggestion, alterations are in *italics*:

People speculate and *trade* in stock marketing. There have been cases of *traders* pumping money *into* a specific stock *in order to create* a fake demand for it which in turn shoots its price *up, leading to further speculation.*